# TypeError: create_int(): incompatible function arguments

Tags: python, opencv, mediapipe

I've Been Recently Learning Computer Vision using python, and when making a hand detector project, I encountered this error :-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\idhant\OneDrive - 007lakshya\Idhant\Programming\Projects\MY MACHINE 
LEARNING PROJECTS\Hand Tracking Module.py", line 64, in <module>
main()
File "c:\Users\idhant\OneDrive - 007lakshya\Idhant\Programming\Projects\MY MACHINE 
LEARNING PROJECTS\Hand Tracking Module.py", line 41, in main
detector = handDetector()
File "c:\Users\idhant\OneDrive - 007lakshya\Idhant\Programming\Projects\MY MACHINE 
LEARNING PROJECTS\Hand Tracking Module.py", line 13, in __init__
self.hands = self.mpHands.Hands(self.mode, self.maxHands, self.detectionCon, 
self.trackCon)
File "C:\Users\idhant\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site- 
packages\mediapipe\python\solutions\hands.py", line 114, in __init__
super().__init__(
File "C:\Users\idhant\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site- 
packages\mediapipe\python\solution_base.py", line 258, in __init__
self._input_side_packets = {
File "C:\Users\idhant\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site- 
packages\mediapipe\python\solution_base.py", line 259, in <dictcomp>
name: self._make_packet(self._side_input_type_info[name], data)
File "C:\Users\idhant\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site- 
packages\mediapipe\python\solution_base.py", line 513, in _make_packet
return getattr(packet_creator, 'create_' + packet_data_type.value)(data)
TypeError: create_int(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types 
are supported:
1. (arg0: int) -> mediapipe.python._framework_bindings.packet.Packet

Invoked with: 0.5
[ WARN:0] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv- 
python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (438) `anonymous- 
 namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
```

And I tried Very Much Debugging it, But Not Successfull :(, So Please Help me, Here's The Code That I've Written:-

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import time

class handDetector():
    def __init__(self, mode=False, maxHands = 2, detectionCon=0.5, trackCon = 0.5):
        self.mode = mode
        self.maxHands = maxHands
        self.detectionCon = detectionCon
        self.trackCon = trackCon

        self.mpHands = mp.solutions.hands
        self.hands = self.mpHands.Hands(self.mode, self.maxHands, self.detectionCon, 
                                        self.trackCon)
        self.mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils

def findHands(self, img, draw=True):
    imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    results = self.hands.process(imgRGB)
    # print(results.multi_hand_landmarks)

    if results.multi_hand_landmarks:
        for handLms in results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            if draw:
                self.mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img, handLms, self.mpHands.HAND_CONNECTIONS)
    return img

            # for id, lm in enumerate(handLms.landmark):
            #     # print(id, lm)
            #     h, w, c = img.shape
            #     cx, cy = int(lm.x*w), int(lm.y*h)
            #     print(id, cx, cy)
            #     # if id == 4:
            #     cv2.circle(img, (cx, cy), 15, (255,0,255), cv2.FILLED)



def main():
    pTime = 0
    cTime = 0
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    detector = handDetector()

while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    img = detector.findHands(img)
    
    cTime = time.time()
    fps = 1/(cTime-pTime)
    pTime = cTime

    cv2.putText(img, str(int(fps)),(10, 70), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 3, (255,0,255),3)

    cv2.imshow("Image", img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)








if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I've Tried Making A Class of Hand Detector, Which Does the same thing to detect hand but we can also use it in our other files, That's why I've written this code, and encountered this issue!

Answer (score 19):

In the `def __init__()`, at the code:

```
self.hands = self.mpHands.Hands(self.mode, self.maxHands, self.detectionCon, self.trackCon)
```

try adding model complexity for the third parameter in the `Hands()` as below:

```
self.hands = self.mpHands.Hands(self.mode, self.maxHands, self.modelComplex, self.detectionCon, self.trackCon)
```

So a total of five parameters in the `self.mpHands.Hands()`

Here is my full code that works for me:

```
class handDetector():
    def __init__(self, mode=False, maxHands=1, modelComplexity=1, detectionCon=0.5, trackCon=0.5):
        self.mode = mode
        self.maxHands = maxHands
        self.modelComplex = modelComplexity
        self.detectionCon = detectionCon
        self.trackCon = trackCon

        self.mpHands = mp.solutions.hands
        self.hands = self.mpHands.Hands(self.mode, self.maxHands, self.modelComplex, 
                                        self.detectionCon, self.trackCon)
```

Comment: I thought `modelComplexity=1`  `self.modelComplex = modelComplexity` will work default but after define manually it work perfectly.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Checked every single place on the internet but could not find a fix for the problem, Thanks.

Comment: Upvoted. OP should accept this answer because it works perfectly. I had the same issue on version 0.8.9.1, not sure if this is an issue on previous versions of mediapipe.

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign one more parameter in the `__init__` method of the `handDetector()` class.

Your complete code may look like:

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import time

# class creation
class handDetector():
    def __init__(self, mode=False, maxHands=2, detectionCon=0.5,modelComplexity=1,trackCon=0.5):
        self.mode = mode
        self.maxHands = maxHands
        self.detectionCon = detectionCon
        self.modelComplex = modelComplexity
        self.trackCon = trackCon
        self.mpHands = mp.solutions.hands
        self.hands = self.mpHands.Hands(self.mode, self.maxHands,self.modelComplex,
                                        self.detectionCon, self.trackCon)
        self.mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils # it gives small dots onhands total 20 landmark points

    def findHands(self,img,draw=True):
        # Send rgb image to hands
        imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        self.results = self.hands.process(imgRGB) # process the frame
    #     print(results.multi_hand_landmarks)

        if self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            for handLms in self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:

                if draw:
                    #Draw dots and connect them
                    self.mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img,handLms,
                                                self.mpHands.HAND_CONNECTIONS)

           return img

    def findPosition(self,img, handNo=0, draw=True):
        """Lists the position/type of landmarks
        we give in the list and in the list ww have stored
        type and position of the landmarks.
        List has all the lm position"""

        lmlist = []

        # check wether any landmark was detected
        if self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            #Which hand are we talking about
            myHand = self.results.multi_hand_landmarks[handNo]
            # Get id number and landmark information
            for id, lm in enumerate(myHand.landmark):
                # id will give id of landmark in exact index number
                # height width and channel
                h,w,c = img.shape
                #find the position
                cx,cy = int(lm.x*w), int(lm.y*h) #center
                # print(id,cx,cy)
                lmlist.append([id,cx,cy])

                # Draw circle for 0th landmark
                if draw:
                    cv2.circle(img,(cx,cy), 15 , (255,0,255), cv2.FILLED)

        return lmlist

def main():
    #Frame rates
    pTime = 0
    cTime = 0
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    detector = handDetector()

    while True:
        success,img = cap.read()
        img = detector.findHands(img)
        lmList = detector.findPosition(img)
        if len(lmList) != 0:
            print(lmList[4])

        cTime = time.time()
        fps = 1/(cTime-pTime)
        pTime = cTime

        cv2.putText(img,str(int(fps)),(10,70), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,3,(255,0,255),3)

        cv2.imshow("Video",img)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue, just add `model_complexity` to your `init` function and you are good to go:

```py
def __init__(self, mode=False, model_complexity=1, upBody=False, smooth=True, detectionCon=0.5, trackCon=0.5):
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it helps by now or probably for future reference.
this is a known issues with the last version of mediapipe.
revert to version 0.8.8 will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem of indentation since findHands() needs to be part of the class handDetector(). So just tab findHands() and it should work

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
def __init__(self, mode=False, maxHands = 2, detectionCon=0.5, trackCon = 0.5):
```

The problem is with this line 6 of the code. The library is updated, you have to initialize an integer value to "detectionCon".
for best results initialize detectionCon = 1 and trackCon = 0.5.

If this solves your problem upvote so others can see it easily.