# (arg0: int) -> mediapipe.python._framework_bindings.packet.Packet

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, mediapipe, cvzone

TypeError: create_int(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
1. (arg0: int) -> mediapipe.python._framework_bindings.packet.Packet

I'm getting this error when I try and run a virtual keyboard code

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:\Programming_projects\Python\VirtualKeyboard\main.py", line 12, in 
detector = HandDetector(detectionCon=0.8)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\cvzone\HandTrackingModule.py", line 33, in **init**
self.hands = self.mpHands.Hands(self.mode, self.maxHands,
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solutions\hands.py", line 114, in **init**
super().**init**(
File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solution_base.py", line 289, in **init**
self._input_side_packets = {
^
File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solution_base.py", line 290, in 
name: self._make_packet(self._side_input_type_info[name], data)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solution_base.py", line 592, in *make_packet
return getattr(packet_creator, 'create*' + packet_data_type.value)(data)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: create_int(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
1. (arg0: int) -> mediapipe.python._framework_bindings.packet.Packet

Invoked with: 0.8

Process finished with exit code 1

I'm getting this error when I try and run a virtual keyboard code. Using mediapipe.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: create\_int(): incompatible function arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69686420/typeerror-create-int-incompatible-function-arguments)

Comment: please learn to use this site. [tour], [ask]